# How to push local Git repo to newly created Google Code project?

Tags: git, qt-creator, google-code

I have a local git repo created by Qt Creator during the New Project Wizard. I've made many commits there. I have created a new Google Code project only now. What is the best way to sync the remote repo to my local one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You  can see an example at [this article "Setting up Google Code with Git"](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/07/setting-up-google-code-with-git.html) from [AlBlue’s Blog](http://alblue.bandlem.com/):

```
$ cd /path/to/existing/local/repo
$ git remote add googlecode https://project.googlecode.com/git
$ git push googlecode master:master
```

See [`git remote`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-remote) command: if you have an existing remote (google code) repo ready, you can add its address to your local repo and start pushing (provided you did setup correctly your `~/.netrc` file as described in the article, or your `%HOME%\_netrc` file for windows: see "[Git - How to use `.netrc` file on windows to save user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031214/git-how-to-use-netrc-file-on-windows-to-save-user-and-password/6031266#6031266)" for more).

Once you have done a local commit, you can push the `master` branch (see "[Push origin master error on new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827351/push-origin-master-error-on-new-repository)"), and from there just `git push googlecode`.
If your remote is called **'`origin`'**, then after the first push, you will be able to just do '`git push`' for the future pushes.

Comment: BTW: how to set up the new remote in a such way that later `git push` would automatically push it there?

Comment: @Kos: I have edited my answer. You would need to call your remote repo 'origin' (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270760/whats-mean-origin-when-git-push)

Comment: @VonC: Thanks for the bit about "Push origin master error on new repo". That was very helpful.