# What is "origin" in Git?

Tags: git

When I run:

```
git push origin branchname
```

What exactly is `origin` and why do I have to type it before the branch name?

Comment: "origin" is the name of the remote repository where you want to publish you commits. By convention, the default remote repository is called "origin", but you can work with several remotes (with different names) as the same time. More information here (for example): http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: Note also that origin is an "upstream" repo: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of 'origin' in 'git push origin master'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270760/whats-the-meaning-of-origin-in-git-push-origin-master)

Comment: But then when using git fetch and then git branch -r local branches are prepended with origin/ ugh :-/ https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch

Comment: Checkout the .git\config file it contains the mappings of aliases to URLs, the .git folder is hidden by default.

Answer (score 751, accepted):

`origin` is an **alias** *on your system* for a particular remote repository. It's not actually a property of that repository.

By doing

```
git push origin branchname
```

you're saying to push to the `origin` repository. There's no requirement to name the remote repository `origin`: in fact the same repository could have a different alias for another developer.

Remotes are simply an **alias** that store the URL of repositories. You can see what URL belongs to each remote by using

```
git remote -v
```

In the `push` command, you can use *remotes* or you can simply use a *URL* directly. An example that uses the URL:

```
git push git@github.com:git/git.git master
```

Comment: Can a single remote be an alias for multiple other remotes? What if I wanted one remote to push to multiple other remotes? For example, push to a primary repo, and a push to a backup repo? Would that be a reasonable thing to want in some situations? EDIT: There are [several solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations).

Comment: What if I omit the "origin" keyword? When we say "git push", isn't it anyway going to push all commits to the remote repository? Adding the keyword "origin" seems redundant.

Comment: @Mugen In the docs for `git push` you can see that it first checks the config for that repository (which you can check with `git config --list`) for a key called `branch.<branchname>.remote`. If that's not set, "it defaults to origin" - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Answer (score 204):

`origin` is **not** the remote repository name. It is rather a local **alias** set as a key in place of the remote repository URL.

It avoids the user having to type the whole remote URL when prompting a push.

This name is set by default and for convention by Git when cloning from a remote for the first time.

This alias name is not hard coded and could be changed using following command prompt:

```
git remote rename origin mynewalias
```

Take a look at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote for further clarifications.

Comment: What if I omit the "origin" keyword? When we say "git push", isn't it anyway going to push all commits to the remote repository? Adding the keyword "origin" seems redundant.

Comment: By default origin is already set, If you see "git remote -v"; Hence when you omit origin, it default connects to remote URL :-)

Answer (score 84):

Git has the concept of "remotes", which are simply URLs to other copies of your repository. When you clone another repository, Git automatically creates a remote named "origin" and points to it.

You can see more information about the remote by typing `git remote show origin`.

Comment: git commands are very confusing to beginners. I guess it has to do with the history of this version control system. So, question: Instead of `git remote show origin`, why not simply `git show origin`? There must be a reason, what is it? Thanks.

Comment: @Stack0verflow: this is probably better asked as a new question so people can do the research if you're curious. 'git show' is already another command that shows a commit, and technically nothing would stop you having a branch called 'origin' in addition to having a remote called origin...

Answer (score 53):

`origin` is the default **alias** to the URL of your remote repository.

Answer (score 42):

**`Origin`** is the **shortname** that acts like an **alias** for the url of the remote repository.

Let me explain with an example.

Suppose you have a `remote repository` called `amazing-project` and then you clone that remote repository to your local machine so that you have a `local repository`. Then you would have something like what you can see in the diagram below:

[image]

Because you cloned the repository. The remote repository and the local repository are **linked**.

If you run the command `git remote -v` it will list all the remote repositories that are linked to your local repository. There you will see that in order to push or fetch code from your remote repository you will use the **shortname** 'origin'.
[image]

Now, this may be a bit confusing because in GitHub (or the remote server) the project is called 'amazing-project'. So why does it seem like there are two names for the remote repository?

[image]

Well one of the names that we have for our repository is the name it has on GitHub or a remote server somewhere. This can be kind of thought like a **project name**. And in our case that is 'amazing-project'.

The other name that we have for our repository is the **shortname** that it has in our local repository that is related to the URL of the repository. It is the shortname we are going to use whenever we want to push or fetch code from that remote repository. And this shortname kind of acts like an **alias** for the url, it's a way for us to avoid having to use that entire long url in order to push or fetch code. And in our example above it is called `origin`.

So, what is **`origin`**?

Basically origin is the **default** shortname that Git uses for a remote repository when you clone that remote repository. So it's just the **default**.

In many cases you will have links to **multiple remote repositories** in your local repository and each of those will have a different shortname.

So final question, why don't we just use the same name?

I will answer that question with another example. Suppose we have a friend who forks our remote repository so they can help us on our project. And let's assume we want to be able to fetch code from their remote repository. We can use the command `git remote add <shortname> <url>` in order to add a link to their remote repository in our local repository.

[image]

In the above image you can see that I used the shortname `friend` to refer to my friend's remote repository. You can also see that both of the remote repositories have the same project name `amazing-project` and that gives us one reason why the remote repository names in the remote server and the shortnames in our local repositories should not be the same!

There is a really helpful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIHIRBz5ZXk)  that explains all of this that can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIHIRBz5ZXk).

Comment: This really helped me understand so much better than the accepted answer! Thank you @Anna Skoulikari

Answer (score 33):

Simple! "origin" is just what you nicknamed your remote repository when you ran a command like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git
```

From then on Git knows that "origin" points to that specific repository (in this case a GitHub repository). You could have named it "github" or "repo" or whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 24):

I was also confused by this, and below is what I have learned.

When you clone a repository, for example from GitHub:

- `origin` is the alias for the URL from which you cloned the repository. Note that you can change this alias.
- There is one `master` branch in the remote repository (aliased by `origin`). There is also another `master` branch created locally.

Further information can be found from this SO question: [Git branching: master vs. origin/master vs. remotes/origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588291/git-branching-master-vs-origin-master-vs-remotes-origin-master)

Answer (score 7):

The best answer here:

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/glossary/origin

> In Git, "origin" is a shorthand name for the remote repository that a
>   project was originally cloned from. More precisely, it is used instead
>   of that original repository's URL - and thereby makes referencing much
>   easier.

Answer (score 7):

I would just add, that it becomes easy to understand if you think about remotes as locations other than your computer that you may want to move your code to.

Some very good examples are:

- GitHub
- A server to host your app

So you can certainly have multiple remotes. A very common pattern is to use GitHub to store your code, and a server to host your application (if it's a web application). Then you would have 2 remotes (possibly more if you have other environments).

Try opening your git config by typing `git config -e`

Note: press <kbd>escape</kbd>, then <kbd>:</kbd>, then <kbd>q</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> to quit out

#### Example

Here's what you might see in your git configs if you had 3 remotes. In this example, 1 remote (called 'origin') is GitHub, another remote (called 'staging') is a staging server, and the third (called 'heroku') is a production server.

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/username/reponame.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "heroku"]
        url = https://git.heroku.com/appname.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[remote "staging"]
        url = https://git.heroku.com/warm-bedlands-98000.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

The three lines starting with `[remote ...` show us the remotes we can push to.

Running `git push origin` will push to the url for '[remote "origin"]', i.e. to GitHub

But similarly, we could push to another remote, say, '[remote "staging"]', with `git push staging`, then it would push to `https://git.heroku.com/warm-bedlands-98000.git`.

In the example above, we can see the 3 remotes with `git remote`:

```
git remote   
heroku
origin
staging
```

#### Summary or `origin`

Remotes are simply places on the internet that you may have a reason to send your code to. GitHub is an obvious place, as are servers that host your app, and you may have other locations too. `git push origin` simply means it will push to 'origin', which is the name GitHub chooses to default to.

#### As for `branchname`

`branchname` is simply what you're `push`ing to the remote. According the git push help docs, the `branchname` argument is technically a `refspec`, which, for practical purposes, is the branch you want to push.

- Read more in the docs for `git push` by running: `git push --help`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers say that `origin` is an alias for the [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) of a remote repository which is not entirely accurate. It should be noted that an address that starts with `http` is a URL while one that starts with `git@` is a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) or Universal Resource Identifier.

All URLs are URIs, but not all URIs are URLs.

In short, when you type `git remote add origin <URI>` you are telling your local git that whenever you use the word `origin` you actually mean the URI that you specified. Think of it like a variable holding a value.

And just like a variable, you can name it whatever you want (eg. `github`, `heroku`, `destination`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**remote**(repository url alias) → **origin**(upstream alias) → **master**(branch alias);

- `remote`, level same as `working directory`, `index`, `repository`,
- `origin`, local repository branch **map** to remote repository branch

Answer (score 1):

I for one got stuck on this early. Consider

```
git push origin master
git log origin..
```

Both are common idioms but the term origin is not being used the same way. The first is used as a remote alias, the second as a remote ref, more explicity written as `git log origin/master~0..master~0` both of which mean give me what's in master not in origin/master with respect to the last fetch; however, it looks for the remote-ref head and branch head to make that comparison by default and in the first case assume the current checked out branch too.

The second command is invalid without that remote ref and the remote ref would be invalid without that remote but in practical use, the term origin can have this meaning too, or any other remote for that matter.