# Git branching: master vs. origin/master vs. remotes/origin/master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I think I'm on the right track to understand the basic concepts of git.

I've already set up and cloned a remote repository. I also created a server side empty repository, and linked my local repository to it.

My problem is that I don't understand the difference between:

- origin/master vs. remotes/origin/master

As far as I have understood, **master** is a local branch, and **remotes/origin/master** is a remote one.

But what exactly is **origin/master**?

Comment: @ChristopherWallace: You provoked two questions on meta with your edit: "[Do we really need an \[origin\] tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298341)" and "[What is the true \[Master\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298343)".

Comment: @Deduplicator Is that a problem?

Comment: @ChristopherWallace: Well, many seem to think both tags (the one you created and the one you just added) are bad. I happen to concurr, but perhaps you have something to add to the discussion linked which wasn't considered. If not, seems so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Comment: Follow up question: Why would `.git/refs/origin/master` ever drift from `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`? This is happening to me now and I'm getting thrown off.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Take a clone of a remote repository and run `git branch -a` (to show all the branches git knows about).  It will probably look something like this:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Here, `master` is a branch in the local repository.  `remotes/origin/master` is a branch named `master` on the remote named `origin`.  You can refer to this as either `origin/master`, as in:

```
git diff origin/master..master
```

You can also refer to it as `remotes/origin/master`:

```
git diff remotes/origin/master..master
```

These are just two different ways of referring to the same thing (incidentally, both of these commands mean "show me the changes between the remote `master` branch and my `master` branch).

`remotes/origin/HEAD` is the `default branch` for the remote named `origin`.  This lets you simply say `origin` instead of `origin/master`.

Comment: Good answer.  I think `git branch -a` showing the remote branch as `remotes/origin/master` is partly because the underlying ref is stored in `.git/refs/remotes/origin` (if it hasn't been packed).  In my opinion, the output of `git branch -a` could be much clearer, perhaps by separating the name of the remote from the name of the branch with something other than a slash.

Comment: Also note that `git branch -r`, which is to show remote branches only, will show the branch as just `origin/master` because the `remotes/` prefix isn't necessary.

Comment: @misterbiscuit: thats true. The output is more confusing than clarifying. Thanks a lot, a great answer to my quesion that gave me the right hints

Comment: If I look at `git log` I see `commit fa9sd8jasdf98 (HEAD -> master)`, what does this mean? What is HEAD in this instance? I thought I was currently "master" and were commiting to `origin/master`. I think I got something mixed up, could someone help calrify? EDIT UPDATE: I think I got it, is it correct to assume that HEAD currently is pointing to the master branch, meaning that I am currently in the process of commiting to master?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen yes you are right, the HEAD -> master part means that you are currently on master branch.

Comment: However, I am a little confused with this answer. Isn't remotes/origin/master is different from origin/master if someone changed the remote master branch and we haven't fetched it yet?

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor if you haven't fetched or pulled yet, your local repo won't _know_ about any new commits from the remote.  `remotes/origin/master` and `origin/master` both point at the same thing: the **last known location** of the `master` branch in the remote called `origin` (i.e. as of your repo's last communication with the remote repo).

Answer (score 116):

Short answer for dummies like me (stolen from Torek):

- ***origin/master*** is "where master was over there last time I checked"
- ***master*** is "where master is over here based on what I have been doing"

Comment: origin/master = backup of remote machine, updated last time you checked
master = your copy of origin/master

Answer (score 44):

Technically there aren't actually any "remote" things at all<sup>1</sup> in your Git repo, there are just local names that *should* correspond to the names on another, different repo.  The ones named `origin/whatever` will initially match up with those on the repo you cloned-from:

```
git clone ssh://some.where.out.there/some/path/to/repo # or git://some.where...
```

makes a local copy of the other repo.  Along the way it notes all the branches that were there, and the commits those refer-to, and sticks those into your local repo under the names `refs/remotes/origin/`.

Depending on how long you go before you `git fetch` or equivalent to update "my copy of what's some.where.out.there", they may change their branches around, create new ones, and delete some.  When you do your `git fetch` (or `git pull` which is really fetch plus merge), your repo will make copies of their new work and change all the `refs/remotes/origin/<name>` entries as needed.  It's that moment of `fetch`ing that makes everything match up (well, that, and the initial clone, and some cases of `push`ing too—basically whenever Git gets a chance to check—but see caveat below).

Git normally has you refer to your own `refs/heads/<name>` as just `<name>`, and the remote ones as `origin/<name>`, and it all just works because it's obvious which one is which.  It's sometimes possible to create your own branch names that make it not obvious, but don't worry about that until it happens. :-)  Just give Git the shortest name that makes it obvious, and it will go from there: `origin/master` is "where master was over there last time I checked", and `master` is "where master is over here based on what I have been doing".  Run `git fetch` to update Git on "where master is over there" as needed.

---

Caveat: in versions of Git older than 1.8.4, `git fetch` has some modes that don't update "where master is over there" (more precisely, modes that don't update any remote-tracking branches).  Running `git fetch origin`, or `git fetch --all`, or even just `git fetch`, *does* update.  Running `git fetch origin master` *doesn't*.  Unfortunately, this "doesn't update" mode is triggered by ordinary `git pull`.  (This is mainly just a minor annoyance and is fixed in Git 1.8.4 and later.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, there is one thing that is *called* a "remote".  But that's also local!  The name `origin` is the thing Git calls "a remote".  It's basically just a short name for the URL you used when you did the clone.  It's also where the `origin` in `origin/master` comes from.  The name `origin/master` is called a *remote-tracking branch*, which sometimes gets shortened to "remote branch", especially in older or more informal documentation.

Comment: Excellent description for a newbie like me, thank you! Clarified why she put the `origin/master` sticker on the `local` repo's graph, and not on the `remote` one (I wholeheartedly recommend Jessica Kerr's "Git Happens" presentation for people new to `git`: https://vimeo.com/46010208. I was scratching my head between 30:00 - 30:19.)

Answer (score 13):

I would try to make @ErichBSchulz's answer simpler for beginners:

- **origin/master** is the state of master branch on remote repository
- **master** is the state of master branch on local repository

Comment: good try but IMHO w/out `last time I've checked` it looses important point

Answer (score 9):

1. **origin** - This is a custom and most common name to point to remote.

`$ git remote add origin https://github.com/git/git.git` --- You will run this command to link your github project to origin. Here origin is **user-defined.**
You can rename it by `$ git remote rename old-name new-name`

---

2. **master** - The default branch name in Git is master. For both remote and local computer.

---

3. **origin/master** - This is just a pointer to refer master branch in remote repo. Remember i said origin points to remote.

`$ git fetch origin` - Downloads objects and refs from remote repository to your local computer [origin/master]. That means it will not affect your local master branch unless you merge them using `$ git merge origin/master`. Remember to checkout the correct branch where you need to merge before run this command

*Note: Fetched content is represented as a remote branch. Fetch gives you a chance to review changes before integrating them into your copy of the project. To show changes between yours and remote `$git diff master..origin/master`*

Answer (score 6):

**I think this git slash notation is probably best understood by looking inside your `.git` folder.**

---

For example, here is a somewhat abbreviated tree of my .git for the LibreOffice source base.

In **linux** `sudo apt-get install tree` is useful to view this.
In **Windows** I think the `tree` command might still work.

Scroll down and take a look at refs (aka 'references') near the bottom:

```
$ tree  
.  
├── branches  
├── config  
├── description  
├── FETCH_HEAD  
├── gitk.cache  
├── HEAD  
├── hooks  
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample  
    ...
├── index  
├── info  
│   └── exclude  
├── logs  
│   ├── HEAD  
│   └── refs  
│       ├── heads  
│       │   ├── master  
│       │   └── remotes  
│       │       └── origin  
│       └── remotes  
│           └── origin  
│               ├── distro  
│               │   ├── cib  
│               │   │   └── libreoffice-6-0  
│               │   ├── collabora  
│               │   │   └── cp-6.0  
│               │   └── lhm  
│               │       └── libreoffice-5-2+backports  
│               ├── HEAD  
│               ├── libreoffice-6-2  
│               ├── master  
│               └── private  
│                   └── mst  
│                       └── sw_redlinehide_4a  
├── objects  
│   ├── info  
│   └── pack  
│       ├── pack-b80087dc57e2b3315f449ca0f1aaa91987bf0c5e.idx  
│       ├── pack-b80087dc57e2b3315f449ca0f1aaa91987bf0c5e.pack  
│       ├── pack-eb4e6808029e712d8d9c2671accbbd98aaeb9a04.idx  
│       └── pack-eb4e6808029e712d8d9c2671accbbd98aaeb9a04.pack  
├── ORIG_HEAD  
├── packed-refs  
└── refs  
    ├── heads  
    │   ├── master  
    │   └── remotes  
    │       └── origin  
    ├── remotes  
    │   └── origin  
    │       ├── distro  
    │       │   ├── cib  
    │       │   │   └── libreoffice-6-0  
    │       │   ├── collabora  
    │       │   │   └── cp-6.0  
    │       │   └── lhm  
    │       │       └── libreoffice-5-2+backports  
    │       ├── HEAD  
    │       ├── libreoffice-6-2  
    │       ├── master  
    │       └── private  
    │           └── mst  
    │               └── sw_redlinehide_4a  
    └── tags  
        └── libreoffice-6-2-branch-point  

32 directories, 45 files
```

---

It might have been less confusing if it was laid out like this, but it wasn't:

```
repositories (i.e. independent trees)
├──local
│  └──master
│
└──origin1
│  └──master
└──origin2
   └──master
```

---

We have three basic types of references: **heads**, **remotes**, and **tags**.

- .git/refs/**heads** holds our local **master**.
- .git/refs/**remotes** can hold a number of remotes, although at the moment we only have **origin** in it.
- .git/refs/**tags** (is discussed elsewhere).

**origin** thus, is our one and only remote.  It holds **origin/master**.

---

We find that we have 2 **HEADS** (pointers to current branches), one local, and one remote:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD                        #         local:  HEAD -> master
ref: refs/heads/master

$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD    # remote origin:  HEAD -> master
ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
```

---

If you list your **branches**:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/aoo/aw080
  remotes/origin/aoo/trunk
  remotes/origin/distro/capgemini/cg-4.1
  remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-0
  remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-1
  remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-2
  ...
```

- The first branch listed (**master**) is the only one which is not a remote.  So in this case we have one local branch.  This is where we'll start our own work from, for our own new branches and subsequent commits.

Next, you may have many remote tracking branches, and we do here.  You know these are remote tracking branches because they are prefixed with '*remotes/*'.  The ones shown here are for the remote named origin.

- So the second line is origin's **current branch** pointer.  Remotes/origin: HEAD --points to--> master.  This shows that in the remote repository, the current branch is their branch named **master**, (not to be confused with our local branch named **master**).
- The remaining branches aren't found in your .git/refs/ tree, but rather you'll find them in `.git/packed-refs`.

When we **git fetch** we download changes from the remote repository, into our remote tracking repository.

When we **git merge** we merge the changes in this local, remote tracking repository into our working local branch or branches, in this case into our master branch.

(When we **git pull** we do both of these two steps in one operation.)

---

It's also interesting to note these **local** and **remote** UUIDs for **master** currently point to the same node (aka 'commit'):

```
$ cat refs/heads/master                   # local         master
1ca409292272632f443733450313de5a82c54a9c

$ cat refs/remotes/origin/master          # remote origin master
1ca409292272632f443733450313de5a82c54a9c
```

So our local master points to the same place as the remote's origin master:

```
[local] master = [remote] origin master
```

---

Finally, I think it's also useful to take a look at `.git/packed-refs`

```
$ cat packed-refs 
# pack-refs with: peeled fully-peeled 
3c1d4742e649fe9c8aed8c2817fe3e1f3364f298 refs/remotes/origin/aoo/aw080
e87c8b7922e9a73e0abb7f9a7a47c9ac3374a826 refs/remotes/origin/aoo/trunk
b70fdffb041c12f124dcc0822b61bf3450e53137 refs/remotes/origin/distro/capgemini/cg-4.1
5dbc3f1754809b9489faaf380b1a4bdbcfbb6205 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-0
cfdbc96ca47d68d6785fd21829a8d61f49d6e591 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-1
5189c8c47461ef09739086e55512fc6a10245273 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-2
3bee5917569ca8e6ee3b086458f5b1a917b88ca1 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-3
92fbe703f9ca480d3a2b8610d87e991c729edf77 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-5-4
05c0a5df66cc69d75280f05b804cf82f3387d42b refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-6-0
7fe193e759b24b90852e6e327115b77114d7b119 refs/remotes/origin/distro/cib/libreoffice-6-1
8187f7aa413e7ef7b377eea2b057d336bf256867 refs/remotes/origin/distro/collabora/cd-5.3
7a6b608591e21ef61dc05cff9fc58da531035755 refs/remotes/origin/distro/collabora/cd-5.3-3.1
....
```

---

No doubt this leaves more questions than answers, but I think it can start to help you answer your own questions about what's what.

Answer (score 5):

One clarification (and a point that confused me):

"remotes/origin/HEAD is the default branch"  is not really correct.

remotes/origin/master was the default branch in the remote repository (last time you checked).  HEAD is not a branch, it just points to a branch.

Think of HEAD as your working area. When you think of it this way then 'git checkout branchname' makes sense with respect to changing your working area files to be that of a particular branch.  You "checkout" branch files into your working area. HEAD for all practical purposes is what is visible to you in your working area.

Comment: More precisely, `HEAD` is a "pointer to a branch" (the actual file in your local repo often contains the string `ref: refs/heads/master`, for instance ... unless it's "detached", which is another thing entirely).  However, there's a bug of sorts in the way `clone` interprets the "remote HEAD": the transfer protocols can't send an indirect branch at all, just a raw SHA-1, so git has a kludge that makes this "mostly work".  Every once in a while someone stumbles across a weird case though.  I kind of wish git did not create `remotes/origin/HEAD` at all, especially when it comes out wrong...