# Intellij Git - Git vs. Local vs. Remote branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Very confused regarding Intellij terminology related to Git branches type.
What are the differences between **Git**, **Local** and **Remote** branches?

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-a-new-branch.html) is documentation that refer to those 3 types.

Comment: Or, although it has a different title, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10588291/1256452 (git-branching-master-vs-origin-master-vs-remotes-origin-master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you cited describes how to checkout (create) a new Git branch from either a *local* or a *remote* branch.  I count two things, not three.  To make things more confusing, both the local and remote branches are actually local.  For the sake of explanation, let's say the branch in question were called `someBranch`, and it had a local and remote version.

The local branch `someBranch` is what you would work on when doing your actual development in IntelliJ.  For all intents and purposes, this is *the* branch `someBranch`.

The remote branch is actually a *tracking* branch.  The remote tracking branch of `someBranch` would likely be called `origin/someBranch` by default, or something like that.  The remote tracking branch exists primarily to sync up with the remote respository.  When you do a `git fetch`, the remote tracking branch is actually what gets updated.  So `origin/someBranch` would receive all the latest updates from the remote, *but* the local branch `someBranch` would *not* be updated.  If you were then to create a branch from the remote branch, you would be using the latest version on the remote repository, and *not* whatever version you have locally.  And there are many scenarios when you would want to do this.