# Bitbucket main branch name shall be master or origin/master?

Tags: git, bitbucket

The main branch shall be called `master` or `origin/master`?

I think it is strange my repository has two different branches (`master` and `origin/master`). Actually I don't need both.

1) How shall I name my main branch and how to "merge" (?) both into one so that not to loose any commits?

2) Right now how can I give a link to my colleague so that he can git clone only origin/master contents (and not master or just all branches)?

Development statred from master branch, then it was continued in origin/master (there was a branch X  from origin/master, then a branch Y from X and finally Y merged into origin/master which is now final)

P.S. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588291/git-branching-master-vs-origin-master-vs-remotes-origin-master), it says local branch (on my PC) shall be called master and remote branch (on bitbucket) shall be origin/master (can also be referred to as remotes/origin/master) - so within Bitbucket.org origin/master is the correct one and I shall somehow unite (merge?) it with master (in Bitbucket) and delete master branch?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> local branch (on my PC) shall be called `master`

That's true.

> remote branch (on bitbucket) shall be `origin/master`

No, that a major misunderstanding. The branch at Bitbucket should also be named `master`.

`origin/master` is not a remote branch, it's a remote-tracking reference. This reference exists at your local repository at PC, not at Bitbucket. The remote-tracking reference tracks the commit last synchronized (pulled or pushed) with Bitbucket, that is it points in your local repository to the commit the branch `master` at Bitbucket pointed to at the last pull/push time.