# What are their differences, remotes/origin/HEAD, origin/main, and remotes/origin/main?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

```
$ git branch -a

* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
```

What are their differences:

- `remotes/origin/HEAD`
- `origin/main`
- `remotes/origin/main`

Comment: useful [Why is there a remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master entry in my git branch -l -a output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613793/why-is-there-a-remotes-origin-head-origin-master-entry-in-my-git-branch-l/18746099)

Answer (score 1):

The `remotes/origin/HEAD` is the branch currently checked out in the `origin` repository, which means if you clone that repository, by default that branch will be checked out first.

The `origin/main` is a remote branch (which is a *local* copy of the branch named `main` on the remote named `origin`)

The `remotes/origin/main`, usually referred to as `origin/main`, is the location of a branch called `main` on the *remote* called `origin` the last time you did a git command. If they're related, `main` will have `origin/main` as its *upstream*.

Look at this question too: [master vs. origin/master vs. remotes/origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588291/git-branching-master-vs-origin-master-vs-remotes-origin-master)

Comment: "*The `remotes/origin/HEAD` is the branch currently checked out in the `origin` repository*" Not exactly. The remote repository is almost always a bare repo and doesn't have any checked out branch. :-)

Comment: "*The `origin/main` is a remote branch*" It's called remote-**tracking** branch and it's actually not a branch at all — it's a special kind of reference; it's moved by fetch/pull/push and cannot be committed to.

Comment: `remotes/origin/main` and `origin/main` are synonyms; one is just the full name of the shorter other. You don't need 2 different paragraphs about them. :-)