# git HEAD indicate different locations with different commands

Tags: git

I currently have two branches dev/A and main. The repository is cloned with `main` branch and I've checked out a new branch called `dev/A`

```
$git branch --show-current
dev/A
main
```

Both of which are pointing to the respective origins as upstream.
My current branch is `dev/A`

```
$git branch --show-current
dev/A
$cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/dev/A
```

Both commands above, as far as my understanding goes, are to pointers of origin/HEAD.
However, `git branch -r` and git tree diagram they tell say that `origin/HEAD` is pointing to `origin/main`

```
$git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/main
origin/dev/A
origin/main
```

And in git tree `origin/HEAD` points to the same git commit as where `origin/main` is when `origin/dev/A` is the latest commit.
But `git log` gives me `HEAD` pointing to `origin/dev/A`

```
$ git log
commit <lastest commit id> (HEAD -> dev/A, origin/dev/A)
# commit details here

commit <lastest commit id from main branch> (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main)
# commit details here
```

Is there a difference between `origin/HEAD` and `HEAD`? If so, what are the differences?

Comment: origin/HEAD is what's on the remote. HEAD is local repo. The two don't have to be related

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/354312/2988730

Comment: This might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64994691/2988730

Comment: The two links were helpful but don't answer my question precisely. But your first answer clarified it.

Comment: That's why I posted them in that order. Glad you found what you needed.