# git push NOT current branch to remote

Tags: git, git-push

Is there a way in git **bare** repository to push a branch that is not in HEAD right now?

For example i have two branches:

```
$ git branch
* master
  another
```

And i have two remotes set: `origin` and `another`.

I need to be able push from `another` to `another/another` just in one command without changing HEAD.

Comment: You might consider not having the exact same name for a remote and a branch. It is confusing.

Comment: You can use `git branch -m another another_branch` or `git remote rename another another_remote`

Comment: @KlasMellbourn, that is just for the purpose of example. Of course i don't have this weird naming.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With `git push` you can specify the remote and the local

```
git push remotename branchname
```

Comment: Does it mean that it will push local another to another/another? I always thought it will push `current HEAD` to another/another.

Comment: Yes. (The second) `another` is a refspec, which (in general) has the form `src:dst`. This means to push the local branch `src` to the remote branch `dst`. If `:dst` is omitted, the local branch `src` is pushed to the remote branch `src`.

Comment: the current HEAD is just the default, but you can specify any branch (o more generally any refspec) as Lars was pointing out

Comment: @LarsNoschinski So technically I can even specify to push local another to remote/master by doing `$ git push another another:master`? (of course that's not what i am going to do, but just want to make sure i understand it right).

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. That would push the content of the local `another` to the remote `another/master`

Comment: As a matter of fact `git push another another` is totally equivalent to `git push another another:another`. I feel like I cannot stand another `another`, though.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but that's because git was written by people who hate documentation.

Comment: I found this explanation was misleading. As of git 2.14.1, I had to do `git push origin mybranch:mybranch`.

Comment: This comment thread has gotten out of hand. Is the only way to do it now `git push origin otherbranch:otherbranch` BTW it's 2019 now.

Answer (score 50):

All those "another another" in the original question, the answer and lots of comments are so confusing (which is a perfect example of why it is important to name your things right in the first place), I can't help helping (pun not intended) to write yet another answer as below.

Q: Is there a way in git (bare) repository to push a branch that is **not** in HEAD right now? For example i have two branches and two remotes. I need to be able push from `feature` to `upstream/feature` just in one command without changing HEAD.

```
$ git branch
* master
  feature
$ git remote
origin
upstream
```

A: Do **git push remote_name branch_name**. In the case above, it looks like this.

```
$ git push upstream feature
```

Q: Does it mean that it will push local `feature` to `upstream/feature`? I always thought it will push current HEAD to `upstream/feature`.

A: Yes. The `feature` part is a *[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)*, which has the form `src:dst`. This means to push the local branch `src` to the remote branch `dst`. If `:dst` is omitted, the local branch `src` is pushed to the remote branch `src`. You can specify a different name as remote branch too. Just do:

```
$ git push upstream feature:cool_new_feature
```

(Thanks @gabriele-petronella and @alexkey for providing materials for this answer.)

Comment: Note that "upstream" is just an alias for a particular remote. Odds are, if you've been following the most typical convention online (ie, you copy paste a lot), it's actually gonna be "origin". See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git

Comment: @Kat: while both `upstream` and `origin` are "just" an alias for a particular remote, they have different meanings, by convention of [github fork workflow](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/). Do not assume you can always replace `upstream` by `origin` in any git command, unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

When I tried to do push a, for the remote, new branch using `--set-upstream` (`-u`)

```
git push MyLocalBranch -u origin MyLocalBranch
```

and I did not have the branch checkout out, I received the error

```
fatal: 'MyLocalBranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thanks to the comment [git push NOT current branch to remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699702/git-push-not-current-branch-to-remote#comment22293744_15699729)

> Yes. (The second) another is a refspec, which (in general) has the
> form src:dst. This means to push the local branch src to the remote
> branch dst. If :dst is omitted, the local branch src is pushed to the
> remote branch src.

from [Lars Noschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647987/lars-noschinski) I figured that the solution was to call

```
git push -u origin MyLocalBranch:MyLocalBranch
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, and not needed as the question is fully and correctly answered. This is more of a diary entry or autobiography of a personal success.

Comment: You are right matt. But the intention was to help out if anyone else stumbled into this answer like I did. Should have created a new question and answered it.