# Confusion over origin, master and "branch" names with remote repository

Tags: git

Git is great and I've been using it for a few years now as a basic user, but some things still puzzle me about the naming used. I'm hoping that someone can help explain what I'm doing in simple terms.

Here's my normal workflow

I create a local repository with

```
git init
```

I add and commit to it as usual.

```
git add *
git commit -m"Some message"
```

After some time, I realise that the project is going to be important or that I need to share it and that I need to have it on a remote repository (yes, in an ideal world, I'd first create it remotely, then clone it locally)

I create a new remote repository on Bitbucket (for example) called **someproject**.

I type this in my local repository folder

```
git remote add somename https://******@bitbucket.org/****/someproject.git
```

I check if it's OK

```
git remote -v
```

I then run this command so that I can overwrite the remote repository.

```
git push --set-upstream somename master --force
```

What I don't understand is the difference between someproject, somename, master, and origin. It all works but I don't understand what I'm doing. I've tried reading a few manuals but I'm always confused.

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Why are you conflating branch names (master) with repository names? The remote repo can have a local alias, which is `somename` in your example and will be shown in your local git config. The actual remote is `someproject`. `origin` is just another alias.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837705/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-remote-in-git-commands

Comment: "I don't understand what I'm doing" Yep. Here's my Git intro: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score 3):

Git's terminology is a mess.  It's no wonder it confuses everyone.

Here are the basics:

- A *repository* is a collection of *commits*, plus information Git needs to find those commits.
- A *commit* is numbered, but its number is large, ugly, and random-looking.  It is a unique-to-that-commit *hash ID*, which Git also calls an *object ID* or *OID*.  Once any one specific commit has "used up" some hash ID, no *other* commit *anywhere in any Git repository ever* is allowed to re-use that hash ID.<sup>1</sup>
- Each commit contains two things:

  - A commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*, rather like an archive (tar or rar or WinZip or whatever).  To keep the repository from becoming enormously fat, these archives contain the files in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format.  So when commits re-use earlier files—most commits mostly re-use most files—they don't get stored *again*, they just get re-used.  A commit that exactly matches some previous commit uses *no space at all* to store the files.  (It uses a tiny bit of space to store the metadata mentioned in the next point.)
  - A commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  There's a *who:* a name and email address.  There's a *when:* a date-and-time stamp.  (In fact, there are two of each of these.)  There's a *why:* the log message that whoever made the commit put in, to explain why they made that commit.  And, crucially for Git's own operation, there's a *list of parent hash IDs*, for the commits that come right before this particular commit.  This commit-hash-ID-list usually has exactly one entry in it.  The entries in this list, plus the commits themselves, *are* the history in the repository: that's all there is!
- In order to *find* commits—because the hash IDs look random—a repository also contains some *names*.  These names are split up into categories:

  - *Branch names* are the ones you use the most, probably.  A branch name has a few special properties, which we'll list in a bit.  But in fact, a branch name just holds the hash ID of one (1) commit!
  - *Tag names* like `v2.1` or `v1.3.5` identify some particular commit: they hold the hash ID of one commit, like a branch name, although some tags—which Git calls *annotated* tags—do this indirectly so that you can add a bit more information, such as a GPG signature verifying that you assert that this particular commit is particularly good and/or useful.
  - Other names: there are a whole host of these, and we'll get back to them in a bit.

That's everything that's in a repository that you will see if you can somehow view the repository from afar.  For instance, if you look at a Git repository stored on GitHub, this is what you'll see directly.

If you can look at it closer up, though, a repository also holds some *configuration*, which you can tweak with `git config` and with other more specialized Git commands, such as `git remote` or `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  You'll have these in Git "clones" that you make locally.  A *clone* is just a copy of a repository, but there are some things to know about a clone:

- Each clone has *its own private configuration*.  Your `git config` settings won't necessarily match those of someone else's clone, or a GitHub clone, or whatever.
- Each clone also has its *own private branch names*.  In fact, all the names are specific to that clone, but Git normally *shares* the *tag* names, so that if they (whoever "they" are) have a `v1.3.5`, you'll have a `v1.3.5` too.

  Note that the *hash IDs* are universal: if you have commit `a123456` and they have commit `a123456`, that's *the same commit* by definition (or at least, it is if you quote the whole hash ID—`a123456` is too short to be a full hash ID, but the real ones are too painful for humans to bother with).  The *branch names* are *not* universal, and my `main` or `master` in my clone can hold a different commit hash ID than your `main` or `master`.  I can have branch names that you don't, and vice versa.
- We like to connect clones to each other now and then, so that we can transfer *commits*.  That's because we like to *make new commits*.  When we do this, we merely *add* to the repository: all the old commits are still there, we've just added a new commit, with a new unique hash ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>This kind of accidental re-use of a hash ID, producing what I like to call a "[doppelgänger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger) commit", would break Git—not to the point of exploding the universe or anything, but the two different Git repositories would be unable to talk with each other.  Not exactly tragic, but that's why the hash IDs are so big and ugly, so that this *doesn't* happen.

---

#### This is where the special property of branch names comes in

Before we dive into *remotes* and such, let's draw some commits in a repository.  Remember, each commit has some big ugly hash ID, and each commit has a list of hash IDs stored inside it—in its metadata—that's usually just one entry long.  So this makes a *backwards-looking chain* of commits.

Since hash IDs are too painful for humans to use, I like to use single uppercase letters to stand in for them.  Let's call our first commit ever commit `A`, and our second commit ever commit `B`, and so on.  We'll draw these like so:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` points backwards to earlier commit `B`.  Commit `B` points backwards to `A`.  `A` has an *empty list of previous commits:* it doesn't point anywhere because there's no earlier commit to point *to*, so that's where history ends—or starts, depending on whether you work backwards (like Git) or forwards.

Note that commit `C` has a full snapshot of every file.  So does earlier commit `B`.  It's by *comparing the snapshots* in `B` vs `C` that Git can tell you what *changed* in commit `C`.  Git can find `B` *from* `C` using the hash ID stored in `C`'s metadata.  But to find `C` from nothing, that's much harder.  Git could root around through every commit in the repository, trying to find the one at the end that has no arrow pointing *to* it, to find commit `C`, but this would take a while.

So, the trick Git uses here is to have a *branch name* point to the *last commit*, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

Git can now read the *name* `main`, which contains `C`'s real hash ID, to find `C`.  Then Git reads `C`'s metadata to find `B`, and `B`'s metadata to find `A`, and `A`'s metadata to discover that `A` is the end (or start) of history.

With this in mind, let's look at how Git *adds a new commit*.  We start by telling Git to *extract* commit `C`.  The files in `C` are all read-only, Git-only things that are useless for doing any actual *work*.  Git has to copy them out of the commit "archive", turning them into ordinary everyday files.  That's the `git checkout` or `git switch` command in operation:

```
git switch main
```

tells Git *extract the commit to which the name `main` points*, i.e., commit `C`.

We'll skip over some very important stuff about Git's index / staging-area here, for space reasons, and just go directly to what happens when you run `git commit` to make a *new* commit.  Git will:

- Gather up all the metadata it needs to make `D`: this includes your name and email address, the current date-and-time, your log message, and—crucially—the actual hash ID of the *current commit `C`*.
- Snapshot all the files that go into the new commit.  This can re-use all the existing files: since all snapshots are always entirely read-only, no existing file will change.  Only *updated* files require new snapshots.  Git has actually already built these, so that `git commit` runs very fast (compared to other pre-Git version control systems anyway).
- Write all this out, obtaining a new unique hash ID, which we'll call `D`:

  ```
  A--B--C   <-- main
         \
          D
  ```
- **The sneaky bit:** Git now writes `D`'s hash ID into the *name* `main`.

The end result is that now `main` points to `D`, in *your* repository:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- main
```

Nobody else's repository has `D` yet, so they cannot possibly have *any* name—`main` or anything else—that points to (their missing copy of) `D`.

This is why your branch names are *yours*.  Your Git is going to *move them around* as you make new commits.  Your repository's branch names are specific to your repository, and some commits—the ones you've made, but not yet sent off to other Git repositories—are also only available to you.

Note that more than one branch name might point to any given commit.  Suppose, for instance, we're up to this point:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

and we now decide we'd like to create a *new branch* named `dev` for development:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main
```

We now have *two names*, both of which select the commit whose hash is `H`.  Git needs to know which *name* we're using, so in our drawings, we add the special name `HEAD`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, main (HEAD)
```

This says that we're using the name `main` to work with commit `H` right now.  If we run:

```
git switch dev
```

(or `git checkout dev`) we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), main
```

We're still using commit `H`, but now we're doing so through the *name* `dev`.  Now when we add a new commit `I`, we get:

```
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

The name `main` *doesn't move*, and the name `dev` *does* move, because we're "on" branch `dev`.  Git writes our new commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*, whenever we make a new commit.  If we make another new commit now, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we switch back to `main`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We still have the two new commits.  Git does, however, *remove* from our work area all the files that go with commit `J`, and put in their place all the files that go with commit `H`.  So now we're working with commit `H`, not commit `J`; we're now `on branch main`, as `git status` will say.  If we make two *more* commits, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- main (HEAD)
```

and now we have what people often call "branches".

#### The word *branch* is very badly overloaded in Git

We have *branch names*, like `main` and `dev`.  These contain one hash ID each, and each one has these special properties:

- We can get "on" the branch, with `git checkout` or `git switch`.  This attaches the special name `HEAD` to the branch name, as in the drawings above, and makes that the *current branch*.  We are now "on the branch".
- We can make a *new commit* while "on the branch", and when we do, our new commit becomes the latest commit "on the branch".

But the word "branch" *also* means the series of commits ending with the *last* one as found by the branch name.  Commits `I-J` are parts of "branch dev".  Commits `K-L` are parts of "branch main".

What about the commits up through `H`?  Those are, in fact, on *both branches*.  They're "part of" both!  So a commit can be on more than one branch at a time.

This makes the word *branch* in Git ambiguous at best, and at worst, useless (because nobody knows what we mean).  It's like being at a party where everyone has the same name.  "Hey Bruce!  Bruce told me to inform Bruce that Bruce can't come, because he's visiting Bruce at the hospital.  Will you go tell Bruce to tell Bruce?"  (Sometimes it's clear from context, but when it's not, be sure to use another word, or be more explicit, e.g., "branch name".)

#### Connecting one Git to another Git: the *remote*

Once we've made new commits—or someone else has made new commits that we'd like to get into our own clone—we find we want to connect two different Git repositories together.  In the ancient past, we had to do this by typing in a URL every time.  This quickly became painful, so Git invented a lot of different ways to get around that.  One of them took root.

To have our Git call up some other Git, we normally use a thing Git calls a *remote*.  A remote is just a short name that—at one level anyway—just stores a URL.  When we first *clone* a repository, with:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git
```

for instance, our Git software creates our new clone with a single remote already set up in it.  This remote's standard name is `origin`.<sup>2</sup>  From now on, you can have your Git software call up that *same repository again*, using this name:

```
git fetch origin
```

calls up the same Git from which you did your clone and *gets* any new commits that they have, that you don't.  Meanwhile:

```
git push origin <insert some arguments here, dropping the angle brackets>
```

*sends* new commits that *you* have that *they* don't.

Except for the transfer direction, these operations are very similar.  But there is one big difference.  We'll get to that in a little bit.

Your Git repository has branch names.  So does their Git repository.

You can add new commits to your branches.  So can they.

To avoid having any new commits *you* added to *your* repository get lost, when you run `git fetch origin` to get *their* new commits from *their* repository, your Git won't touch your *branch names*.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can select another name, if you like, with the `-o` option, at `git clone` time.  The usual rule for most people is: Don't do that, as you'll just make things more painful for yourself.

---

#### Remote-tracking names

To make this work, the initial `git clone` you run copies *all their commits* but *none of their branch names*.  Instead, having gotten all their commits, your Git takes each of their *branch* names—`main` or `master`, `dev`, `feature/short`, whatever—and *renames each one*.  Their `main` becomes your `origin/main`.  Their `dev` becomes your `origin/dev`.  Their `feature/short` becomes your `origin/feature/short`.

In other words, for each of their *branch* names, your Git software creates a *different name* in your repository.  It *renames their branches*.  I call these renamed things *remote-tracking names;* the official Git documentation calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, which uses that poor overloaded word *branch* yet again.<sup>3</sup>

After doing all this renaming, the initial `git clone` *creates* one branch name in your new clone.  You choose which name it should create: you run `git clone -b dev url`, for instance, if you want your Git to create your `dev` based on their `dev`.  Your Git takes your renamed `origin/dev` and makes one `dev` that points to the same commit as your `origin/dev`, which your clone made point to the same commit that their `dev` pointed-to.  (Whew!)  If you don't use `-b`, your Git asks their Git software what branch name *they* recommend, and that's normally `master` or `main`, whichever they're using.

After that, you can create more branch names.  The `git switch` and `git checkout` commands have a *guess* mode (you can turn this off with `--no-guess` if you want), where if you run:

```
git switch rudy
```

and you don't *have* a branch named `rudy`, your Git will look for an `origin/rudy` and if it finds one, create your own `rudy` based on your `origin/rudy`, just like your initial `git clone` did with `main` or whatever.

So, after you've created a local branch name of the *same name* as some remote-tracking name, and made some new commits, you can run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and your Git will call up the other Git software, at the URL saved under the *remote* name `origin`, and get any new commits *they* have on *their* branches.  Having done that, your Git will create or update your *remote-tracking names*, `origin/*`, based on their *branch* names.

This sort of thing produces the exact same kind of "branching"—here's the overloaded word again—that we saw before:

```
          I--J   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/somebranch
```

and now you get to figure out what to do about this.  The fact is that Git really cares about the *commits*, not the branch names, here: the `origin/somebranch` remote-tracking name works just as well to find commit `L` as any branch name would.

The key differences between your *branch names* and your *remote-tracking names* are:

- you can get "on" your branch names, and make new commits and make them update automatically;
- you can't get "on" your remote-tracking names: `git switch origin/somebranch` gives you an error.<sup>4</sup>  Just use `git fetch` to get these updated.

If and when you find yourself in this situation, it's time to learn about, or use, `git merge` and/or `git rebase` (but we won't cover those here).

---

<sup>3</sup>[Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)

<sup>4</sup>The old `git checkout` command doesn't give you an error, but puts you in a mode Git newbies should generally mostly avoid, which Git calls *detached HEAD* mode.  Don't do that until you're ready.

---

#### `git push` is different

Using `git fetch origin`—with no additional arguments—has your Git call up the Git over at `origin` and get *all* their new commits and update *all* your remote-tracking names.<sup>5</sup>  This is fairly easy, and almost always harmless.<sup>6</sup>  That is, you can run `git fetch` at any time: if there are no new commits to get, it quickly does nothing, and if there are new commits, it gets them and updates your remote-tracking names, and all is good.

But with `git push` you must—well, sometimes—name not only the *remote*, `origin`, but also a *branch name*, e.g.:

```
git push origin feature/tall
```

to push your new feature branch.  This:

- sends to `origin` commits that you have on your `feature/tall` branch, that they don't have anywhere (it doesn't send new commits on your `dev` though); then
- asks them to set *their* `feature/tall` **branch name**.  This normally takes the form of a polite request.

That is, you don't have them set some reserved-to-you remote-tracking name.  You have them set a *branch* name in their repository.

If they are already using that branch name for something else, they'll usually *refuse your request*.  The jargon-y error they give you for this is:

```
! [rejected]        feature/tall -> feature/tall (fetch first)
```

What this means is: *I did not obey your polite request, because a branch name can only remember one commit.  The one commit you asked me to remember would cause me to forget some other commits.*  That is, they may have had:

```
...--G--H--K--L   <-- feature/tall
```

and you asked them to set their repository up with:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- feature/tall
         \
          K--L   ???
```

If they do that, they'll *stop being able to find* commits `K-L`.

Sometimes—especially when using `git rebase`—this kind of thing is exactly what you *want* them to do, and when you *do* want them to do that, you have to modify your `git push` command.  Instead of ending with a polite request, you have to end that `git push` with a forceful command: *Set your branch!  Now!  DO IT NOW!*  Or something along these lines.

Since this is just covering the basics—all of the above *are* basics!—we won't go into detail on when and how you *should* use the various kinds of "force-push", as Git calls them.  Just be aware of the difference: the polite kind of push means *don't lose work*, and the forceful kind is required if you mean "yes, do lose work, I mean it!"  To avoid losing work, avoid the forceful kind of push.

---

<sup>5</sup>If you make a so-called *single-branch clone*, this stops working (on purpose).  Don't do that until you're ready to learn about single-branch clones.

<sup>6</sup>The word *almost* is only here to account for the occasional horrible mistake, where someone accidentally pushes a commit that contains a multi-hundreds-of-gigabytes file to some corporate server.  (GitHub would reject this push so it won't happen there.)  Then you, a hapless Git newbie, run `git fetch` and your Git downloads this multi-gigabyte commit and it uses up most of your disk space on your laptop, or something.  That's not exactly harmless—and since Git doesn't ever like to *give up* a commit, it can be a pain to recover from.

---

#### In your particular case, you do mean to lose work (on GitHub)

Now, let's note that for your particular setup here, you created a repository on your laptop, say, with `git init`, and did some work locally.  This made a bunch of commits.

Then you said to yourself: "Hey, I think I'd like to publish this project."  So you went over to (say) GitHub, using their web interface.  You had them create, for you, a repository.

When GitHub create a repository, they optionally stick into it a first commit.  The *first* commit in any repository—the one we saw above as "commit `A`"—is a little weird because a branch name cannot exist until there is a commit.  So GitHub will offer to make your repository *with a first commit in it*.

This first commit isn't *your* first commit, in *your* repository on your laptop.  It's a *different first commit*.  So you have, on your laptop:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

Meanwhile over on GitHub (or wherever) you have created a new repository and had *GitHub* create a new commit *there*—let's call this one `N` for New—and that's the one commit in the GitHub repository:

```
N   <-- main
```

You run:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/you/repo.git
```

for instance, to set up the *remote* name `origin`.  Then you run:

```
git push origin main
```

Your Git will call up GitHub's software.  They'll connect to `you/repo.git` over there.  That repository has one commit, `N`, found by the branch name `main`.

Your Git will send over commits you have that they don't: that's the `A-B-C` chain.  Then your Git will politely ask that they set *their* `main` to point to commit `C`.

They will refuse, because that will *lose* commit `N`.  Do you want commit `N`?  If you do, get it from them (`git fetch`) and so something with it.  If not, just tell them: *yeah, ok, lose that commit* with a `git push --force`.

#### In the future, consider having them create an *empty* repository

GitHub, among other hosting providers, *will* allow you to create a *totally empty* repository.  This has no commits and no branches, so that when you run your initial `git push`, you send over your commits and ask them to create a branch.  This won't lose any commits—there are none!—so they'll accept the polite request, and you're all set.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look at the git clone command. It's pretty simple. Just cloning a repository automatically sets up the default upstream remote as the origin.

A few other things:

1. If you haven't, I'd try to avoid using `--force` in push commands. Use it when you want to overwrite history, but when you are just adding new commits - like right now, you don't need it. See the "Undoing changes" guide for more details.
2. You can use the same git remote name for multiple repositories - meaning that if you pull from bitbucket, GitHub, and gitorious one after another your repository will have all three histories merged together in a nice way and that you can push to all of them (with origin as only named remote). This is because of the branch merging feature.

Comment: this is no answer for what have been asked