# In Git's terminology, is `origin` a ref or something else?

Tags: git

[In Git's terminology](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary), is `origin` a ref  or something else?

Is it correct that `origin` is defined as a configure variable `remote.origin.url` in a configure file such as `.git/config`?

Must a ref  be a file for example `.git/refs/heads/*`? If yes, can `origin` still be a ref?

Comment: The word "reference" is not defined in the terminology document you linked to.  Are you using that word interchangeably with "ref" or something?

Comment: Some relevant info here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: It is a `remote`. A remote is a repository whose branches you track. A remote has some properties like `url`, `pushurl`, `fetch`, `push`, etc. These properties are defined as `remote.origin.url`, `remote.origin.pushurl`, etc. A ref can be a file or an entry in `.git/packed-refs`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529518/6309

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `origin` is a string of six characters.  Whether it has any meaning anywhere depends on the "anywhere".

Longer answer: yes, `origin` is a ref or something else.

OK, that's not long enough, so let's go a bit longer:

- Some Git commands look for a *remote*.  When you run `git clone`, if you don't use the `-o` option, you get a remote named `origin`, so:

  ```
  git remote show
  ```

  will list `origin`.  That's a valid remote.
- Some Git commands look for a *commit specifier* or a *tree specifier* or similar.  Here, if you use a string of letters that *cannot be mistaken for a hash ID*, Git will go through the six-step resolution process outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  I'm not going to quote that documentation here, but note that one of the six steps looks to see if `refs/remotes/name/HEAD` exists.  If `origin` is a valid remote, and `git fetch` has run in the usual way, there is almost certainly a valid `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` that translates to a valid commit hash ID.

Hence `origin` is a valid form of ref-name, *when Git tries to use it as one*.  It's also a valid remote, *when Git tries to use it as one.*

Note that some Git commands look for both remote names *and* commit specifiers.  In that case, `origin` can be used in *both positions* and have *both meanings:*

```
git push origin origin:newbranch
```

for instance.  The first `origin` is a remote and the second is a ref.