# what is the origin branch in git? how to use it?

Tags: git

I am a newbie of git, I try to understand what is origin and origin/master in git, what does the origin means? where it is? and someone says it is remote branch, what is the remote branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is `origin` in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529497/what-is-origin-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's mean 'origin' when git push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270760/whats-mean-origin-when-git-push)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`origin` is the default name given to the remote repository from which your local repository was cloned. `origin/master` is the `master` branch of that repository, which (by default) your local `master` branch will track.

Answer (score 4):

See the ProGit book and [Working with Remotes](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html). Origin usually refers to the git repository that you cloned from.

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

to fetch changes from the original repo.

```
git push origin master
```

to push from your local master branch to origin (and its master branch). You have to have commit rights to be able to do this.

[Github's help](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/) is really great as well and describes how to add your own remotes (like an upstream remote after you fork a project).