# How do I add files to a git repository?

Tags: git, repository

I am working on something in github, sharing a repository.

I took the following steps:

```
 $ git clone   https://github.com/Company/repos
 Cloning into repos...
 Username: 
 Password: 
 warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

(yes, I realize the repos is empty. I am supposed to add files to it, but can't:)

```
 $ cd repos
 $ echo hello > README.txt
 $ git add README.txt
 [no output]

 $ git commit -m "commit"

 [master (root-commit) 824324d] commit
 Committer: User <email@host.com>
 Your name and email address were configured automatically based
 on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
 You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

     git config --global user.name "Your Name"
     git config --global user.email you@example.com

 After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

     git commit --amend --reset-author

  1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
  create mode 100644 README.txt
```

(So that file seems to be in.)

Now I do:

```
  $ git push
  Username: 
  Password: 
  Everything up-to-date
```

Nothing is uploaded to the repository! If I clone it again, the files are not there.

EDIT: following someone's request:

```
  $ git add README2.txt 
  $ git status
  # On branch master
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  #     new file:   README2.txt
  #
```

Comment: Is README.txt an existing non-empty file or do you try to create it via `git add`?

Comment: @marioebl it is an existing file, I created it.

Comment: Could you include the output of `git status` after `git add`?

Comment: Ok try `git push origin master` then.

Comment: Do you have to use command line? I would try to use a gui: gitk or sourcetree. Maybe its showing whats wrong with your local clone.

Comment: Please include the output of `git remote -v show` and `git branch -vv`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the github repository is linked in as remote origin? Without it push has no target.

Comment: I don't know. I didn't create the repository. Should I tell that person to do something with it?

Comment: No it has to be set in your local clone. Or you could specify the complete url after your push. Dont know the exact syntax.

Comment: Now here is the syntax: git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repository.git and after that you could try a 
git push origin master

Comment: You should not have to set the origin for a clone of an existing remote repository: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270788/3263412

Comment: That is right, you should not have to. But something does not work here. Are you sure without to observe it that origin is there?