# How to create new remote branch from GITHUB?

Tags: github

I want to create new remote branch in github and I didn't find it in the UI.

is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it form github you need to do it from command line

Comment: did you really try the link I've shared at my answer? Because I've created branch from **GITHUB** site

Comment: Yes I tried I want to create new remote branch not on orion but new remote. with your steps I succeed to create new branch under orion.Did you succeed to create new remote branch not under orion ?

Comment: I think you are misleading ``origin``. ``origin`` is the default name of the remote git repository you cloned from. You could follow this the get a concept about ``origin`` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270760/whats-the-meaning-of-origin-in-git-push-origin-master